# GCC - "has initializer but incomplete type" error when using macros for function attributes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, macros, function-attributes

I have a few header files with some simple glorified `struct`s with just pure virtual methods defined within them. The code compiles fine on Windows with Visual Studio 2015, but GCC is getting stuck. First, the code:

## Code Listing

---

```
namespace CustomUtils
{
    interface API_ABSTRACT overriden
    {
        virtual int GetStatus() const = 0;
    };
}
```

---

In an imported header file, `interface` is just defined as a `stuct`:

```
#define interface struct
```

And `API_ABSTRACT` is just a macro for nothing:

```
#define API_ABSTRACT
```

The `interface` `typedef` is part of inherited code I have no control over, and the `API_ABSTRACT` is in place so that I can [define custom attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in Windows and Linux to limit which API functions I export. While this builds in VS2015, on Linux, I get a build error:

---

```
error: variable 'API_ABSTRACT CustomUtils::overridden' has initializer but incomplete type
```

---

If I change the line:

```
interface API_ABSTRACT overriden
```

To what I presume it is being translated to:

```
struct overriden
```

The code will compile fine in Linux. I've tried compiling with `gcc -E -dD` to have the post-"pre-processed" source rendered to screen to see the `typedef` and `#define` substitutions, but it seems to only show the output for `.cpp` files, and not header (`.h`) files.

## The Question

Why won't this code work when attempting to compile with GCC?

Thank you.

---

## Edit #1

---

The output from `gcc -E` shows the offending line to be:

```
struct API_ABSTRACT overriden
```

So it seems the culprit is the `API_ABSTRACT` macro, which evaluates to nothing.

Comment: What do you meant by *interface is typedefed to struct*?

Comment: @SergeyA Please refer to updated question. Will update in 30 secs.

Comment: `typedef struct interface;` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: @SergeyA Corrected again. Was working from memory on little sleep.

Comment: Can't be. with `#define` like that the code will be identitcal. You really need to use `-E`, just give it a .cpp file which includes header in question.

Comment: @SergeyA Edited question and posted results under the `Edit #1` subsection. Getting closer.

Comment: Show us your code that defines API_ABSTRACT in GCC.  (The actual code, copy and pasted, not your sleep-deprived recollection of what it should look like).  Put a #error immediately below that line, and see if the error is reported.

Comment: Are you sure all includes are in the right order? It seems to me that `#define API_ABSTRACT` is missing in some files.

Comment: If that is a **true** output of gcc -E, it means that `API_ABSTRACT` is not defined anywhere. As simple as that.

Comment: Done (added as complete anaswer as I can). Oh boy, what I wouldn't do for an upvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API_ABSTRACT was not defined anywhere (the corresponding file was not included). The way to check it is through tell-tale `gcc -E`:

```
struct API_ABSTRACT overriden
```

With `-E`, gcc would show preprocessed output, and having API_ABSTRACT in plain sight there means preprocessor knew nothing of it.

When C++ compiler have seen this construct (`struct API_ABSTRACT overridden`), it thought (according to grammar and if you grant compilers cognizance) that `overriden` is a variable of type `API_ABSTRACT`. Followed by braces, it turned the construct into initialization of said variable. However, type API_ABSTRACT was never defined, so compiler complained about initializing a variable of incomplete type.

Comment: Thank you. Question though: why doesn't the compiler spit out a less vague warning, ie: `API_ABSTRACT` not defined?

Comment: @Dogbert, compilers do their best to guess your intentions and tailor messages for them, but it's hard when grammar is brutally violated.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!